# Flutter plugin java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of error for aar library

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-platform-channel

I have created a plugin which is just a wrapper around native sdk for android and ios. For Android I have aar file which I have imported in the plugin . I can access the sdk class in the plugin file in the IDE, But when I run the example app of the plugin then the app crashes with error as class def not found for the files of the sdk. I have done analysis of the apk it had classes jar which contained those files of the sdk. Below are the logs.

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(39)] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/xyz/xyzapp/sdk/xyzSDK;
E/flutter ( 6844):  at com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz.xyzPlugin.onMethodCall(xyzPlugin.java:72)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:231)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:93)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:642)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
E/flutter ( 6844): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xyz.xyzapp.sdk.xyzSDK" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
E/flutter ( 6844):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/flutter ( 6844):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/flutter ( 6844):  ... 11 more
E/flutter ( 6844):
F/flutter ( 6844): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(76)] Check failed: CheckException(env).
F/libc    ( 6844): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 6844 (flutter_example), pid 6844 (flutter_example)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:8.1.0/OSM1.180201.007/4586646:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 6844, tid: 6844, name: flutter_example  >>> com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(76)] Check failed: CheckException(env).
'
eax 00000000  ebx 00001abc  ecx 00001abc  edx 00000006
esi a94aa6c0  edi 00001abc
xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
eip adcccac4  ebp bfa9f308  esp bfa9f298  flags 00200286
backtrace:
#00 pc 00000ac4  [vdso:adccc000] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
#01 pc 0001edf8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
#02 pc 0001f073  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+115)
#03 pc 0115a7f7  /data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x113f000)
#04 pc 011485fb  /data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x113f000)
#05 pc 01146390  /data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x113f000)
#06 pc 011abd29  /data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x113f000)
#07 pc 01158efd  /data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x113f000)
#08 pc 0115b549  /data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x113f000)
#09 pc 0115b48e  /data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x113f000)
#10 pc 01161b40  /data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x113f000)
#11 pc 01161b6e  /data/app/com.rajeevjaiswal.xyz_example-6n39Rpe9t5iTFKT4PxjmgA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x113f000)
#12 pc 00014af7  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::SimpleLooperCallback::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+39)
#13 pc 00015936  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+982)
#14 pc 000154d6  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+118)
#15 pc 000e25cb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, int)+59)
#16 pc 007d5428  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x606000) (android.app.NativeActivity.onWindowFocusChangedNative [DEDUPED]+136)
#17 pc 00642262  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
#18 pc 001160cf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+223)
#19 pc 0032153f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+335)
#20 pc 0031a7a4  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+836)
#21 pc 0062942c  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+428)
#22 pc 006333a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14369)
#23 pc 002f3a2b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
#24 pc 002fa2e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+231)
#25 pc 0031a78a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+810)
#26 pc 00627e14  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+756)
#27 pc 006332a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14113)
#28 pc 002f3a2b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
#29 pc 002fa2e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+231)
#30 pc 0031a78a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+810)
#31 pc 0062964a  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+282)
#32 pc 00633421  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14497)
#33 pc 002f3a2b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
#34 pc 002fa1cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*)+139)
#35 pc 006179bf  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1311)
#36 pc 0064832d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
#37 pc 00642432  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
#38 pc 001160f9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+265)
#39 pc 00544d6b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+91)
#40 pc 00546f65  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+1573)
#41 pc 004adfb3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*)+83)
#42 pc 002677a8  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x1db000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+168)
#43 pc 00642262  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
#44 pc 001160cf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+223)
#45 pc 0032153f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+335)
#46 pc 0031a7a4  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+836)
#47 pc 00627e14  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+756)
#48 pc 006332a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14113)
#49 pc 002f3a2b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
#50 pc 002fa1cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*)+139)
#51 pc 006179bf  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1311)
#52 pc 0064832d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
#53 pc 0160d52d  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x606000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2669)
#54 pc 00642432  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
#55 pc 001160f9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+265)
#56 pc 00544d6b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+91)
#57 pc 00544b3c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*)+764)
#58 pc 0041b39b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+907)
#59 pc 001521f6  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+2950)
#60 pc 0014036b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+75)
#61 pc 0007497e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+62)
#62 pc 000783e8  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+824)
#63 pc 00001db2  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+1602)
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem?